# base64 decode for ISO-8859-1

Tags: c, base64, iso-8859-1

I have the following string.
"this is a test string (à) with (ä) some western europe chars (ß)"

Using http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp
I get the following base64 encoded string.

dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Qgc3RyaW5nICjgKSB3aXRoICjkKSBzb21lIHdlc3Rlcm4gZXVyb3BlIGNoYXJzICjfKQ==

When I try decode this with a C function, I get the following:

./test
Input string is : dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Qgc3RyaW5nICjgKSB3aXRoICjkKSBzb21lIHdlc3Rlcm4gZXVyb3BlIGNoYXJzICjfKQ==
Output string is : this is a test string (�) with (�) some western europe chars (�)

```
int main()
{
  char *in = "dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Qgc3RyaW5nICjgKSB3aXRoICjkKSBzb21lIHdlc3Rlcm4gZXVyb3BlIGNoYXJzICjfKQ==";               
  char out[100]="";
  printf("Input string is : %s\n",in);
  base64_decode(in, out);
  printf("Output string is : %s\n",out);

  return 0;
}
```

It cannot display the upper characters of the iso-8859-1 charset.

I tried the same string with the code from 
http://base64.sourceforge.net/b64.c
./b64 -d infile outfile

infile contains:
dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Qgc3RyaW5nICjgKSB3aXRoICjkKSBzb21lIHdlc3Rlcm4gZXVyb3BlIGNoYXJzICjfKQ==

The outfile produced gives back the expected string. 
When I open it (in emacs or vi), I can see:

> "this is a test string (à) with (ä) some western europe chars (ß)"

But when I cat the file, it shows:

```
cat outfile 
this is a test string (�) with (�) some western europe chars (�)
```

locale settings are all UTF8 but anyone know why there is a difference between print/display on standard out and viewing in file?

I was going to start debugging the base64_decode() function but the display may be a red herring.

Any thoughts appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: You ought to rate the quality of the software roughly proportional to the web site's color scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Your input string is contained in char array and your collecting decoded result in out variable,which is also char array. 
The base64 decoded string can contain the wide character letters.So your printf statement not able to recognize the wide characters.
So what I suggest you is you take input string as of type wchar_t and collect the result into the out  variable which must of type wchar_t. 
And use wprintf to display result.

Thanks